# Exact image for downloading Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have an HP laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 issued by my college. But since I am more of a Windows guy, I installed Windows 8 to it. However, when the laptop was issued, I was told that I should not change the OS. Now that the academic year is ending, I have to give the laptop back to the college, and for that, I need to change the OS back to Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me where can I download the exact OS??

I don't know what is this, here is the link to an image of the exact release version

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There it is.
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

1. Download the iso.
2. Make a bootable CD/USB
3. Install

It's an updated version of the same OS you had installed. But that should be no problem. It would have looked like that if you had used it daily and updated it as necessary.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Hope they won't notice the change